# background image in a wrapper

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am working with a wp theme Mercor - http://mercor.premiumcoding.com/demo.php - the theme contains a slider with a full width background colour.

I need to make this colour an image - I've searched all over and no matter what I do, the image doesn't seem to show up. I am unsure if I should be placing the bg coding into the CSS or the html for the page the slider is on.

I know that the image needs to go into the #slider-wrapper - but nothing I have tried has worked.

help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the background color is placed on this div: id="slider-wrapper"

The css for this is on options css as you can inspect with your browser, I use chrome:

```
media="all"
#contactform .contactbutton .contact-button:hover, .gototop, .role, .team .icon img,      .pagewrap, .blogpostcategory .posted-date .date-inside, #slider-wrapper, .errorpage, .content ol.commentlist li .reply a, .blogpostcategory .comment-inside, ins, .widget_login .submitbutton, .widget_price_filter_custom .ui-slider .ui-slider-handle, .widget_price_filter_custom .ui-widget-content, .item4 .image, .item3 .image, .item2 .image, table.shop_table .carButtons .button:hover, table.shop_table .coupon .button:hover, .cartTopDetails .product_list_widget .buttons a:hover, .widget_price_filter_custom .price_slider_amount .button:hover {
background: #35C2D8;
```

Just change the background property for:

```
background-image: url("the url for your background image")
```

Tell me if it works. It worked for me using the chrome inspector:

```
background-image: url("http://www.poleronesparacolegios.com/poleron.jpg");
```

Maybe that wordpress theme that you are using has an admin option for changing the background without hardcoding the css files.

Comment: Oh my gosh it worked! 

The only issue still is that when I resize my browser the image will shrink down, but not stretch once I've done so, is there any way to fix this? Thank you all so much by the way, I really appreciate the help!

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achive but try this: 
    background-size: contain;
    background-position:center;
@user3111775

Comment: Sorry, I probably didn't explain it so well - I am new to coding. I want the Bg image to be liquid, resizable with the browser. 

would - Background-size: auto; - do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a background style to the .anythingSlider element in the custom css script. I would recommend adding **!important** to the style so it works no matter what the other styles in the theme are.

```
.anythingSlider {
    background-image:url("http://address/to/your/image.jpg") !important;
}
```

Don't forget to set any repeat properties that are needed.

Answer (score 0):

remove this: `background: #35C2D8;`

and add this line :`background: url(yourimage.jpg);`